# quicksort algorithm to sort words in C

Tags: c, arrays, string, char, quicksort

In one of my assignments on my online course, I have to use the quicksort algorithm to sort a list of words.  I was able to sort a list of numbers but not words.  The function IthChar takes in 2 arguments, a string and an integer representing the index of the string, and returns the character located in the index's place.
For example IthChar("Paul", 0) --> P

Here is the quicksort, swap and swapPivot functions:

```
void quickSort(string array[], int left, int right)
{
      int I, J, pivot;
      char chI, chJ, chPivot;

      if(left<right)
      {
                    pivot=left;
                    I=left;
                    J=right;
                    while(I<J)
                    {
                               chI=IthChar(array[I], 0);
                               chJ=IthChar(array[J], 0);
                               chPivot=IthChar(array[I], 0);
                               while(chI<=chPivot&&I<right)
                               I++;
                               while(chJ>chPivot)
                               J--;
                               if(I<=J)
                               {
                                       swap(array, I, J);
                               }
                    }   
                    swapPivot(array, pivot, J);
                    quickSort(array, left, J-1);
                    quickSort(array, J+1, right); 
      }
}

void swap(string array[], int loc, int loc1) 
{
          int temp;

          temp=array[loc];
          array[loc]=array[loc1];
          array[loc1]=temp;
}     

void swapPivot(string array[], int pivot, int J)
{
          int temp;

          temp=array[pivot];
          array[pivot]=array[J];
          array[J]=temp;
}
```

Thanks :D

Comment: Are you sure it's C and not C++? And what is the question? The only question mark here is in this comment.

Comment: Also, note that `temp` is declared as an `int`, but you later assign a `string` to it: `int temp; temp=array[pivot];`

Comment: You should simply write `std::sort(strVector.begin(), strVector.end());`...

Comment: yes it is in c, the question is why it prints nothing

Answer (score 0):

You should write (or reuse if you already have one) a string comparison function.

Comment: or use `strcmp` from `<string.h>`

Comment: @AdrianJandl That's what I was thinking, but I had the impression due to the weird ``IthChar`` that OP was reimplementing strings.

Comment: considering he is assigning them to a normal `char` I assumed `IthChar` to be a function that doesn't follow naming conventions.

Comment: @PaulFilch: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/79804/whats-stackexchange-ese-for-op